# getWindow().setFlags() not working on button click in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I want to disable soft keyboard when we click some button without affecting selection or cursor.
I tried many examples to disable edittext but nothing matched my requirement except this one.

`getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM)`;

The above line disables soft keyboard without affecting selection and cursor.

Now this line only works if I place it under `onCreate()`, otherwise not working. I want to disable editext when user click some actions.
Thank you

Comment: use the setFocusable property.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
Do you mean setFocusable(false) for edittext?

Comment: Yes. The editext won't be editable anymore.

Comment: Yes. that disables editing. As I said before I don't want my edittext to be not editable or not selectable. I just dont want soft keyboard to be appear.

Comment: Yes if that property is set. The soft keyboard wont appear.

Comment: getWindow().setFlags() works perfectly fine for my requirement but it needs to be declared on onCreate() but I want to use it in button click

Is there anything that we can do to update the window manager that we had set the flag or something?

Comment: Then i think you can put the code in UIMain thread i.e          Classname.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {}});

Comment: Let me try..
Thank you